# Java - list iterator not working on IdentityHashMap

Tags: java, iterator

I am using an identity hash map to keep track of objects that I have seen before in a custom serializer. I have a while loop in which I attempt to iterate over entries in the map. During the method call `addAllFields` its possible that objects are added to the keyset of the map. After some debugging I have noticed that my `iterator.hasNext()` returns false even when I know for a fact that object have been added to the map since the last loop body execution. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public Document serialize(Object obj) throws Exception {
    reset();
    addToMap(obj);
    Set<Object> keys = map.keySet();
    Iterator<Object> iterator = keys.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Object key = iterator.next();
        Element objectElement = createObjectElement(key.getClass().getName(), map.get(key));
        addAllFields(objectElement, key);
        document.getRootElement().addContent(objectElement);
    }
    return document;
}
```

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong here?"* Modifying the map while iterating. Javadoc of [`keySet​()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html#keySet--) says: *If the map is **modified while an iteration** over the set is in progress, the results of the iteration are **undefined**.*

Comment: Is there another hash map that you know of that doesn't have this sort of undefined behavior?

Comment: [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). Javadoc of [`keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet--) says: *The view's iterators and spliterators are [weakly consistent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly)*, i.e. guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ListIterator`, and then if you want to iterate over added elements too you need to do the whole thing in reverse:

```
ListIterator<Object> iter = keys.listIterator(keys.size());
while (iter.hasPrevious()){
    Object prev=iter.previous();
    // do your Element creation here
    // then use the iter.add() method
    iter.add(/*new object*/);
}
```

NB you may need to wrap you keyset in a different collection type as not all support ListIterator, and will probably need to pass iter as an argument to #addAllFields() 
You will likely also need to iterate over entry set rather than keySet

Comment: Thanks for your potential solution. Could it be because I need to use a different map implementation that guarantees some sort of ordering? How about a linkedhashmap?

Comment: I think the exact solution depends on whether anything you add in #addAllFields() can itself add more entries when it is processed?  I don't think there is a Map implementation which supports adding during the iteration, which leaves you with something like

    List<Map.Entry<Object,V>> l = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet()); // V is the map value type
    ListIterator<Map.Entry<Object,V>> iter = l.listIterator();

And then as above in my answer.  At the end, if you really need `map` updated, then you will have to add any new entries from `l`